# How to use loop to find a pair of divisors that also add up to a certain sum?

Tags: c

Given two numbers, n and q, I want to find two numbers, m and p, such that n=m*p and q= m+p. I compiled the code but it returned the error message every time even if the entered values are valid. Is something wrong with the loop?

edit**
input n: 100
input q: 25

still returns the error message even if m=20, p=5 works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){


    int *mAddress = NULL;
    int *pAddress = NULL; 

     int n; 
     printf("enter integer: ");
     scanf("%d", &n);

     int q; 
     printf("enter query number: ");
     scanf("%d", &q); 

    int m;
    int p; 
    for (m=1; m<=n; m++){
        if(n%m == 0){
            p = n/m;
            if (m+p == q){
                mAddress = &m; 
                pAddress = &p;
                printf("The values are %d %d", m, p);
                break; 
            }
            else{
                printf("could not find any numbers");
                break; 
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get and what are your inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not break the loop in the case you don't find it for the first time. Instead you should continue this to happen for each `n%m == 0` case.

Eventually when you know that nothing hasn't been found print the error message.

I've added a bool to hold if you have found a pair or not and use it to print the error message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){


    int *mAddress = NULL;
    int *pAddress = NULL; 

    int n; 
    printf("enter integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int q; 
    printf("enter query number: ");
    scanf("%d", &q); 

    int m;
    int p;
    bool found = false;
    for (m=1; m<=n; m++){
        if(n%m == 0){
            p = n/m;
            if (m+p == q){
                mAddress = &m; 
                pAddress = &p;
                printf("The values are %d %d", m, p);
                found = true;
                break; 
            }
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        printf("could not find any numbers");
    }
}
```

[Try it out yourself](https://onlinegdb.com/S1kImqQQU)

Answer (score 0):

You miss for loop bracket after if.

```
    for (m=1; m<=n; m++){
    if(n%m == 0){
        p = n/m;
        if (m+p == q){
            mAddress = &m; 
            pAddress = &p;
            printf("The values are %d %d", m, p);
            break; 
        }}
```